# What does this code mean in the makefile of pmoncfg tool?

Tags: makefile, bootloader

```
BISON?= bison -y
PROG=   pmoncfg
SRCS=   files.c gram.y hash.c main.c mkheaders.c mkioconf.c mkmakefile.c 
OBJS=   files.o hash.o main.o mkheaders.o mkioconf.o mkmakefile.o pack.o       
CFLAGS+=-I${.CURDIR} -I. -DYY_SKIP_YYWRAP
LEX=flex
CLEANFILES=gram.c scan.c gram.h pmoncfg.cat8
MAN=    pmoncfg.8
.y.c:
    ${BISON} -d -o $@ $< 
${PROG}: ${OBJS}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LIBS}
install:
    cp ${PROG} ${DESTDIR}/bin
clean:
    ${RM} -rf ${OBJS} ${CLEANFILES} ${PROG}
```

".y.c: ${BISON} -d -o $@ $<" What does this line mean? There's no .y file in the current folder. And the MAN and LEX variable,the makefile doesnot use it,either.Why declare them?

According to the latest implicit rules, Can I just write "${PROG}: ${OBJS} ${CC} -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LIBS}"?

Comment: I don't understand your last question. What are the "latest implicit rules" and why would you write something to override the implicit rules with an explicit rule if you *want* to use implicit rules?

Comment: Oh,I mean .y.c is an ancient rule, isn't it?  It means all .c files depends on .y files,  there's no .y files but .c files in the current file. So I thought that I don't need to regerate .c files from .y files. According to implicit rules, just gerate .o file from .c file and then gerate pmoncfg from .o files.  I think remove the .y.c line won't make any difference. I'm not sure.

Comment: No, it means if there is a `.y` file and no `.c` file, here is how to generate the dependent `.c` file from the `.y` file with the same base filename.  There should be a `gram.y` which presumably is used to generate `gram.c`.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/kisom/pmon/tree/master/tools/pmoncfg there is a `gram.y` and also a `scan.l` so the `LEX` declaration is actually used as well, though -- as you can probably infer -- through an implicit rule.

Comment: Yeah,exactly,You're right. There's a gram.y file in the current folder. You mean the .y.c line placed here mainly acts for generating gram.c from gram.y. However, when lacks files.c file for example, there's a files.y file, then it can gerate files.c again right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of confusion here seems to be due to the reliance on implicit rules for *some* of the targets.  Looking at https://github.com/kisom/pmon/tree/master/tools/pmoncfg, the file `pmoncfg.8` is manual page source (so will generate `pmoncfg.cat8` through implicit rules)  and `scan.l` is a Lex file (so `scan.c` will be generated with `flex`, as the standard implicit rule parametrizes the program to use in the variable `LEX`).  And contrary to what you write, there is a file `gram.y` which is used to generate `gram.c` using `bison`.

The job of `make` is to find files which can be generated from other files.  A pattern rule like `.y.c` means that if a `.c` file is required but is missing, but there is a corresponding `.y` file, here's how to generate the required `.c` file.  If the file already exists (and is newer than the file it depends on), nothing is done.  If a file already exists and there is nothing to generate it from, obviously nothing needs to be done (and if it's missing and there is no rule for how to generate it, `make` signals an error).

Comment: The standard way to say thanks is to click the "up" arrow next to an answer.  Wink wink, nudge nudge (-:  Glad I could help.

Comment: Lex and Yacc or their somewhat modernized GNU replacements Flex and Bison are specialized code generators for building parsers. They generate C code which usually outperform hand-written scanners and parsers, and/or is easier to develop, understand, maintain, and extend.  The man page format is not used to generate a `.c` file at all; it's sort of like a specialized prehistoric HTML.

Comment: Rather than ask random questions, perhaps you should read an overview like [The Art of Unix Programming](http://catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/).

Comment: Here's TAOUP on [lex and yacc](http://catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch15s03.html#id2979797).